# Selecting checkbox from different rows randomly in a table with data that constantly changes

Tags: typescript, playwright

The set changes constantly so every time I am in this flow I want to randomly select(checkbox) one set from the table randomly how do I do that? For example the code automatically select set 2 one time the next time it will select set 5. Please help, I use codegen so I am not that familiar with coding.

[image]

**This is the code**

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://xxxxxx.com');
  await page.locator('#email').click();
  await page.locator('#email').fill('xxx@gmail.com');
  await page.locator('#password').press('CapsLock');
  await page.locator('#password').fill('xxx@123');
  await page.locator('#password').press('Enter');
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Receiving Station' }).click();
  await page.locator('[id="\\32 778"]').check();
});

});
```

(Once in this receiving station screen I want to randomly select a set as related to the screenshot shared above)

[image]

Comment: Is 'https://xxxxxx.com' actually the site? Please share the real one, or a [mcve] of it so the code is runnable. If you can't, at least markup HTML of the element subtree in the screenshot would be useful for writing an answer. That said, randomization in tests is generally a bad idea. I would try to make tests as deterministic as possible, so that if you get a failure you can easily understand and reproduce it. Just write 6 or so tests that click each one, or that click the edges and a couple from the middle if all 6 feels excessive.

Comment: I added a screenshot of element subtree

Comment: Thanks, but it's still pretty hard to write an answer. I don't see a "Receiving Station" element or an element with that id you're using in that subtree. Please share the actual site or a runnable example of it, [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). I should be able to copy-paste into my IDE, run it and see what you're trying to do, so I can write a working, verified solution.